# drupal ckeditor HTML tag issue

Tags: html, drupal, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in drupal
and add some html tags in it like div and span
but all are converted into <p> at the site 
but if I recheck that in ckeditor it showing ok but not on site

and not able set class on tags which has declare in style.css of theme

Any idea

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What input format is on that field? Your site will typically have two input formats unless you've changed the default, Full HTML (which is only available to admins) and Filtered HTML. You can view and configure your input formats at /admin/settings/filters/list, by default Filtered HTML only allows:

```
<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd>
```

If you allow `<span>` and `<div>` in the input format you are using, it should work.

Comment: Thanks ZoFreX.. Now I select the Full HTML and it done.... But I am not getting the point "Full HTML (which is only available to admins)"...... Even after logout it works... can you please tell me What exactly with Full HTML

Comment: By default, only the administrator user can input data using the "Full HTML" format (but anyone can view the content they make), but that can be changed. If you configure it from /admin/settings/filters/list, you can choose which roles can use it. I would recommend against letting all users use Full HTML, and instead add the tags needed to a filtered format (if you do need users other than yourself editing things)